# How to make a Qt App for iOS & android using CMakeLists.txt

Tags: android, ios, qt, cmake, cmake-gui

I have a pure `C++` console app which runs on `OSX` & I need to extend it as *cross-platform (iOS+Android+OSX)* with a simple *UI* for which I am planning to use commercial `Qt`. The app's code compiles on `g++` as well as `clang++`. I verified it by making a `.pro` & ran it on `iOS` & `android`. It works fine.

**But I want to maintain the app with `CMakeLists.txt` instead of a `.pro` file. Is it possible ?**

Importing the `CMakeLists.txt` into the `QtCreator` gives all options for `android, iOS & OSX` but doesn't load the source code files !

**How can I make a Qt app for iOS & android using CMakeLists.txt ?**

Comment: You could try to create a test project from scratch using CMakeLists.txt... not sure if Qt Creator can do it for you. Also one thing that comes to mind is, if you have several build system files in the same folder for same project, and that confuses Qt Creator.

Comment: There seems to be no way to create a project from scratch on QtCreator & output a `CMakeLists.txt` instead of a `.pro` file. I am looking for answers around importing an existing `CMakeLists.txt` into QtCreator & somehow make it work ? if possible ?

Comment: Have you tried the File->New File or Project->Import Existing Project-Import Existing Project feature? It adds separete Qt Creator project files (which contain the files in it and the commands you want to use to build it).

Comment: I tried it. Importing an existing `CMakeLists.txt` into `QtCreator` does not work

Comment: Qt should work with `CMakeLists.txt` additionally. it would be so convenient to port existing projects to Qt